# Fulfilling Chainlink Job requests not successful

Tags: solidity, chainlink

fulfilling request for ATestNetConsumer.sol failed. Every time I request for current ethereum price it always returns uint256: 0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unAGb.png)

I followed the steps carefully but I don't know what I am missing - https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/.

Please help, the codes and contract address are listed below:

Oracle Contract Address: "0xC3b625566d22aBd0C6Ce659105bE29054D03BFa4"

EVM Chainlink Address:
"0x711715E74FfDf0c22eC43607a03732Cefcfc60A7"

_jobId = "76eb4b9925014082bb58389e3ffd7f6a"

```js
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Uint256"
externalJobID = "76eb4b99-2501-4082-bb58-389e3ffd7f6a"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0xC3b625566d22aBd0C6Ce659105bE29054D03BFa4"
minIncomingConfirmations = 0
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
    multiply     [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times=100]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(multiply) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0xC3b625566d22aBd0C6Ce659105bE29054D03BFa4" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

Here is for the contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract ATestnetConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY;
  uint256 public currentPrice;
  int256 public changeDay;
  bytes32 public lastMarket;

  event RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    uint256 indexed price
  );

  event RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    int256 indexed change
  );

  event RequestEthereumLastMarket(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes32 indexed market
  );

  constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender){
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
  }

  function requestEthereumPrice(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumPrice.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "USD");
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumChange(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumChange.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    // req.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.CHANGEPCTDAY"); // Chainlink nodes prior to 1.0.0 support this format
    req.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,CHANGEPCTDAY"); // Chainlink nodes 1.0.0 and later support this format
    req.addInt("times", 1000000000);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumLastMarket(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumLastMarket.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    string[] memory path = new string[](4);
    path[0] = "RAW";
    path[1] = "ETH";
    path[2] = "USD";
    path[3] = "LASTMARKET";
    req.addStringArray("path", path);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(_requestId, _price);
    currentPrice = _price;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumChange(bytes32 _requestId, int256 _change)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(_requestId, _change);
    changeDay = _change;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumLastMarket(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _market)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumLastMarket(_requestId, _market);
    lastMarket = _market;
  }

  function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
    return chainlinkTokenAddress();
  }

  function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
  }

  function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(_requestId, _payment, _callbackFunctionId, _expiration);
  }

  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
      return 0x0;
    }

    assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
      result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }
}
```

The contract address for ATestNetConsumer.sol is funded.

Comment: Welcome! Can you outline your steps exactly or if you have resolved perhaps answer your own question please?